# Python - Dict nest in List nested in Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

When I do requests.get I'm given back a response that looks like this, the data is from the LoL API:

```
{
"champions": [
    {
        "id": 111,
        "stats": {
            "maxChampionsKilled": 2,
            "maxNumDeaths": 5,
            "mostChampionKillsPerSession": 2,
            "mostSpellsCast": 0,
            "totalAssists": 25,
            "totalChampionKills": 2,
            "totalDamageDealt": 40838,
            "totalDamageTaken": 27900,
            "totalDeathsPerSession": 5,
            "totalDoubleKills": 0,
            "totalFirstBlood": 0,
            "totalGoldEarned": 11070,
            "totalMagicDamageDealt": 21083,
            "totalMinionKills": 56,
            "totalPentaKills": 0,
            "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 12876,
            "totalQuadraKills": 0,
            "totalSessionsLost": 1,
            "totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
            "totalSessionsWon": 0,
            "totalTripleKills": 0,
            "totalTurretsKilled": 1,
            "totalUnrealKills": 0
        }
    },
```

I'm struggling getting the data that is inside of "stats." What I really want to do is is something similar to the following:

```
champ_data = received['champions']['stats']['totalSessionsPlayed']
print(champ_data)
```

However it isn't working because after "champions" there is a '[' and I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: `[]` means it's a list, then you have to index it. `received['champions'][0]['stats']['totalSessionsPlayed']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this

```
received['champions'][0]['stats']
```

for the first champion's stats.  Or, this

```
received['champions'][n]['stats']
```

for the *nth* champion's stats.  Or, this

```
[champion['stats'] for champion in received['champions']]
```

for a list of each champion's stats.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting so frustrated, and I knew it had to be a fairly easy mistake I was making. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`received['champions']` is a list. To process all entries (if that's what you want to do) you have to iterate it:

```
for champion in received['champions']:
    print(champion['stats']['totalSessionsPlayed'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, do a bit check on the data object you receive in case the property `champions` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your example 'champion' is a list with one element.
This list element can be accessed by champion[0].
This list's element is a dictionary with 2 key:value pairs.
'stats' is a key of 2nd pair which can be accessed by champion[0]['stats'].
Again the value of 'stats' key is a dictionary, whose any key's value eg value of 'totalSessionsPlayed'  can be accessed by
      champion[0]['stats']['totalSessionsPlayed']